# Резиновая квадратная модульная сетка с границами

Tags: html, jquery, css

### Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать подобный «паттерн»:

[image: Сетка и блоки]

при том что функциональная единица — квадрат `□`, скажем, 17×17px с двумя диагоналями `×` и двумя срединными перпендикулярами  `+` (выделен на картинке красным).

---

*Необходимо постоить подобную единицу средствами CSS, jQuery (?), а затем затайлить её, но должно быть всё ровненько.*

#### Как я себе это представляю:

1. чтобы определялась начальная ширина окна, и считалось, сколько примерно может влезть квадратов (`q=округлить в большую сторону(vw/17px)`), затем формировалось бы максимально возможное количество цельных квадратов в ряду по ширине вьюпорта `n`:

  - т.е. если последний квадрат в ряду уйдет за край вьюпорта, скажем, >75%, тогда размер каждого квадрата чуть-чуть увеличивается, так чтобы 100% ширины последнего квадрата выходило за границы вьюпорта (этот квадрат можно удалить), *в итоге видимый ряд получится* `n=q-1`;
  - а если это значение в окрестностях ≈50% (т.е. от 50±25% ширины квадрата), тогда подтягивается до середины, *в итоге получится ряд что-то вроде* `n=q∓0.5`;
  - если выступает за край вьюпорта <25%, то размер всех квадратов уменьшается так, чтобы 0% выходило за край вьюпорта; *в итоге видимый ряд получится* `n=q'`;

2. также размер полученного квадрата передавался бы и служил
   знаменателем к размерам всех блоков (как бы становился единицей
   измерения, назовём её `sqar`).Так чтоб, например, я мог назначить
   какому div'у свойства:

   `{top: 2sqar;  left: 2sqar;  width: 8sqar; height: 2sqar;}`;
3. после того как размер одного квадрата получен, при
   изменении ширины окна, чтоб больше ничего не пересчитывалось, а лишь ужимался
       бы/увеличивался бы размер квадрата, т.е. чтоб во вьюпорте оставался
       один и тот же контент, только лишь зумился бы, и параллельно зуму (т.е. изменению высоты и ширины квадрата) уменьшалась бы
   толщина линий квадрата.

---

Я новичок в этом деле, так что прошу прощения, если где-то звучал глупо, или для решения подобной проблемы требуется неоправдано много времени.

Очень помогли бы примеры.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.